# javascript ~ turn a div into a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my code onto a page where I am not allowed a lot of changes; the person hosting the page allows me a `<script>` tag & a `<div>`,  that's it.

```
--- page ---
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/myJSfile.js'>
</head>
<body>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
</body>
------------
```

When the page loads, how do I turn `mydiv` into a button, when I can only customize `myJSfile.js`?

I cannot promise any typical libraries such as jQuery will be loaded for me,
the host's site does load CSS, but I don't know the structure of their styles.  Maybe I will have to learn some of it at some point.

If my code needs to load jQuery, I first have to check that it isn't already loaded.  How would you do that specifically that check?

If I need to load my own css then I will have to do so dynamically using `myJSfile.js`

`myJSfile.js` js file can be anything I need it to be.  I have full control over it.

How would you go about this?

Please remember that, besides `myJSfile.js`, I am pretty much locked out of anything on the page except the script & div tags.

Comment: This sounds like an "[XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)" problem; so what problem are you trying to solve, why do you need to convert an existing element into a `<button>` (or otherwise add a `<button>` element)?

Comment: I'm thinking I'll just dynamically add a button inside the `div`.  The button is going to redirect the browser to a dynamically set of page per user.  Because that is what I'm being directed to do.

Comment: I guess instead of being a XY per-sey, I'll say I have been presented with a challenge and and constraints.  How I'm looking for advice on how to structure a solution.  I'm open to variations within the bounds of the constraints.

Comment: In order that we can add a complete answer for you, can you [edit] your question to include that information, also such details as the URI to which a user should be redirected and, if that URI depends on identifying a given user, explain how the script should identify the page to which a given user should be redirected?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'll just challenge that the button need do more than console.log('something');  If I can just get the button on the page then I can get through the .onclick()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insertbefore()` function to add the new element, then the `remove()` function, to remove the existing `<div>` element:

```
// Create a <li> node:
var newItemDocument.createElement("LI");
// Create a text node 
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");

// Append the text to <li>:
newItemDocument.appendChild(textnode);
// Get the <ul> element to insert a new node:
var list = document.getElementById("myList");

// Insert <li> before the first child of <ul>:
list.insertBefore(newItemDocument, list.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: But that is jQuery isn't it?  This is where I thought this would go too.  But everything I find uses jQuery with these functions.  Also I'll add to my question that the button needs to appear when the page is first rendered

Comment: No, [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is part of the DOM API, not jQuery; you're *probably) thinking of [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before).

Comment: var newItemdocument.createElement("LI");          // Create a     <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");  // Create a text node
newItem.appendChild(textnode);                    // Append the text to <li>
var list = document.getElementById("myList");    // Get the <ul> element to insert a new node
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);  // Insert <li> before the first child of <ul>

Comment: This is how to do the same using pure JavaScript you can find it on w3school

Comment: @Osama: please [edit] your answer to include the code, otherwise it's an unreadable mess in the comments and is less likely to be read by future visitors.

Comment: Please Thomas can you edit it for me I use my phone and I can not edit it from here

Comment: @Osama Thanks.  You are being greatly helpful.  I too actually came across the 'Water' example on on w3Schools ... but in context of jQuery.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd take a moment to try and offer an answer that might anticipate your future requirements of adding event-listeners to the element(s) you want to insert, and perhaps replacing multiple elements with a common element:

```
// using a named, rather than an anonymous, function in
// order that the same function can be reused multiple
// times:
function replaceElementWith(opts) {

  // these are the default settings:
  let settings = {
    'replaceWhat': '#mydiv',
    'replaceWith': 'button',
    'text': 'this is a button',
    'eventHandlers': null
  };

  // here we iterate over all the keys in the
  // (user-supplied) opts Object to override
  // the defaults; we do this by first retrieving
  // the keys of the opts Object, which returns
  // an Array of those keys, and iterating over
  // that Array using Array.prototype.forEach():
  Object.keys(opts).forEach(

    // here we use an arrow function syntax, since
    // don't need to work with an updated 'this'
    // within the function.
    // key : the current key of the Array of keys,
    // here we update the current key of the
    // settings Object (or add a new key to that
    // Object) to the same value as held in the
    // opts Object:
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  // in order to allow you to perform the same replacement
  // on multiple elements, we use document.querySelectorAll()
  // to retrieve all elements matching the supplied CSS
  // selector, and then pass that Array-like NodeList to
  // Array.from(), which converts an Array-like structure to
  // an Array:
  let targets = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll(

        // this is the CSS selector passed via the
        // opts.replaceWhat value (here '#mydiv'):
        settings.replaceWhat
      )
    ),

    // here we create a new element according to the value
    // passed via the settings.replaceWith value:
    newElem = document.createElement(
      settings.replaceWith
    ),

    // an empty, uninitialised variable to hold the cloned
    // newElem element within the loop (later):
    clone;

  // we set the textContent of the created Element to be
  // equal to the passed-in text, via the opts.text property:
  newElem.textContent = settings.text;

  // here we iterate over the Array of found elements that
  // are to be replaced:
  targets.forEach(

    // again, using an Arrow function expression:
    target => {

      // here we clone the created-element, along with
      // any child nodes:
      clone = newElem.cloneNode(true);

      // unfortunately Node.cloneNode() doesn't clone
      // event-listeners, so we have to perform this
      // step on every iteration, we first test to
      // see if settings.eventHandlers is a truthy
      // value (so not the default null):
      if (settings.eventHandlers) {

        // if there are eventHandlers, then we retrieve
        // the keys of the settings.eventHandlers
        // Object as above:
        Object.keys(settings.eventHandlers).forEach(

          // using Arrow function again;
          // the keys of this object are the event-types
          // we're listening for and the values are the
          // functions to handle that event, so here
          // we add the 'eventType' as the event,
          // and the 'settings.eventHandlers[eventType]
          // (which retrieves the function) as the handler:
          eventType => clone.addEventListener(eventType, settings.eventHandlers[eventType])
        )
      }

      // here we find the parentNode of the element to be
      // replaced, and use Node.replaceChild() to add the
      // new element ('clone') in place of the target element:
      target.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, target)
    })

}

// calling the function, passing in values:
replaceElementWith({

  // CSS selector to identify the element(s) to be removed:
  'replaceWhat': '#mydiv',

  // the eventHandlers Object to define the
  // created element's event-handling:
  'eventHandlers': {
    // in the form of:
    // 'eventName' : eventHandler
    'click': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.location.hash = 'buttonClicked';
      this.style.opacity = this.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5;
    },
    'mouseenter': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = '#f90';
    },
    'mouseleave': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = 'limegreen';
    }
  }
});
```

```js
function replaceElementWith(opts) {
  let settings = {
    'replaceWhat': '#mydiv',
    'replaceWith': 'button',
    'text': 'this is a button',
    'eventHandlers': null
  };

  Object.keys(opts).forEach(
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  let targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(settings.replaceWhat)),
    newElem = document.createElement(settings.replaceWith),
    clone;

  newElem.textContent = settings.text;

  targets.forEach(
    target => {
      clone = newElem.cloneNode(true, true);
      if (settings.eventHandlers) {
        Object.keys(settings.eventHandlers).forEach(
          eventType => clone.addEventListener(eventType, settings.eventHandlers[eventType]);
        )
      }
      target.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, target)
    })

}

replaceElementWith({
  'replaceWhat': '#mydiv',
  'eventHandlers': {
    'click': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.location.hash = 'buttonClicked';
      this.style.opacity = this.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5;
    },
    'mouseenter': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = '#f90';
    },
    'mouseleave': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = 'limegreen';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #f90;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xar5euk2/).

The below demo does exactly the same as above, but does so working with multiple elements to be replaced, and the only change made is to the function call:

```
replaceElementWith({
  // changed this selector to select by class,
  // rather than id (and added multiple elements
  // to the HTML):
  'replaceWhat': '.mydiv',
  'eventHandlers': {
    'click': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.location.hash = 'buttonClicked';
      this.style.opacity = this.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5;
    },
    'mouseenter': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = '#f90';
    },
    'mouseleave': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = 'limegreen';
    }
  }
});
```

```js
function replaceElementWith(opts) {
  let settings = {
    'replaceWhat': '#mydiv',
    'replaceWith': 'button',
    'text': 'this is a button',
    'eventHandlers': null
  };

  Object.keys(opts).forEach(
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  let targets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(settings.replaceWhat)),
    newElem = document.createElement(settings.replaceWith),
    clone;

  newElem.textContent = settings.text;

  targets.forEach(
    target => {
      clone = newElem.cloneNode(true, true);
      if (settings.eventHandlers) {
        Object.keys(settings.eventHandlers).forEach(
          eventType => clone.addEventListener(eventType, settings.eventHandlers[eventType]);
        )
      }
      target.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, target)
    })

}

replaceElementWith({
  'replaceWhat': '.mydiv',
  'eventHandlers': {
    'click': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.location.hash = 'buttonClicked';
      this.style.opacity = this.style.opacity == 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5;
    },
    'mouseenter': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = '#f90';
    },
    'mouseleave': function(e) {
      this.style.borderColor = 'limegreen';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #f90;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xar5euk2/1/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
- [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).